What do yokais and aliens have in common?
In episode 2 of the anime of Dandadan, when Momo and Okarun are attacked by the sumo alien, and the yokai doorbell works on him, Okarun explains that people who sees yokai can also see aliens or something like that, meaning yokai and aliens have something in common. Is this further explained in the manga?
What do yokais and aliens have in common?
